# Guard clause in Ruby not always that convenient

Tags: ruby

I am a bit mitigated concerning the use of Guard Clauses in Ruby.

The style that is suggested by Rubocop is to use the "do if condition_fails"

Often I want to generate useful error messages with the guard clause, which results in long lines if I want to keep use the aforementionned style, and the "if" will often be pushed off the screen (I don't like line wrapping).

The problem is that as a developer, I don't really care about the error message but rather the code condition itself (which is sometimes more explicit than the error message).

Example of a Guard Clause which hides visibility for the dev

```
def crtical_function(params)
  fail Exception.new("Useful message for the user, but not often useful message for the dev, and as you can see this line is veeeeeeerrrrrry long and just annoying because the dev is rather looking for the condition itself which is often more einteresting than an error message") if not_enough_params
end
```

Without the Guard clause style, you understand right away

```
def crtical_function(params)
  if not_enough_params
    fail Exception.new("Useful message for the user, but not often useful message for the dev, and as you can see this line is veeeeeeerrrrrry long and just annoying because the dev is rather looking for the condition itself which is often more einteresting than an error message") 
  end
end
```

So hum yeah the story is that I just installed rubycop and it started highlighting a lot of things including those `if condition fail end` code blocks suggesting to transform them to Guard clauses. I wasn't sure how to react to these.

Is there a setting to configure or maybe a workaround to preserve developer visibility while getting rid of complaints of not writing a guard clause ? What are your suggestions to compromise visibility/guidelines compliance ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Rubocop does not suggest a modifier `if` if the resulting line would exceed 80 characters.

Comment: WTF would an exception ever have a message that END USER of the app would see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very subjective. First of all, in both cases you are breaking another de-facto convention that wants a line of code to not exceed 80 chars.

All these conventions are inheritance from the days when monitors were reasonably small, hence having long lines was uncomfortable and could possibly hide important statements as you noticed.

Personally, I use the one-line style only when performing pre-validation, in general at the beginning of the method or when I have several short conditions in sequence.

Regardless the style you use, you may also want to consider extracting the message in a variable so that the final code is more readable.

```
def critical_function(params)
  message = "Useful message for the user, but not often useful message for the dev, and as you can see this line is veeeeeeerrrrrry long and just annoying because the dev is rather looking for the condition itself which is often more einteresting than an error message"
  fail Exception.new(message) if not_enough_params
end

def critical_function(params)
  message = "Useful message for the user, but not often useful message for the dev, and as you can see this line is veeeeeeerrrrrry long and just annoying because the dev is rather looking for the condition itself which is often more einteresting than an error message"

  if not_enough_params
    fail Exception.new(message) 
  end
end
```

Extracting the message also allows you to store it in a constant and/or freeze it, and/or perform other interpreter optimizations.

Furthermore, you can also consider to wrap the string.

Finally, speaking of conventions, I'd be more worried about following the naming conventions for the methods, rather than forcing to one style for the if-statement.

Ruby methods are `underscore_case`, not `camelCase`:

```
critical_function
```

and not

```
criticalFunction
```

Comment: Under the present version of Ruby, optimizing a string is irrelevant from extracting it outside a method, or freezing it.

Comment: Is `80 chars` limit still around or its bit relaxed - may be 140 chars given most monitors/laptops can afford that many characters?

Comment: @WandMaker StackOverflow's code blocks are about 80 characters wide.

Comment: @Simone thanks for the suggestions and sorry about that snake_case, I'm usually pretty serious about it as well. 
Yes this is indeed subjective but I was wondering how people were actually coping. Also having small monitors is actually still an issue because nowadays, even if we have large monitors, we usually split the screen between several apps and the problem remains the same.